XPATH img import
I'm new to this, I want to take a image from another site, but a blank page appears. The codes I used are below, how can I fix this problem?
<?php


$url = "simple url";


$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);


$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($data);


$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);


$elements = $xpath->query('//*[@id="list-rankup"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[6]/img');


foreach ($elements as $element) {
    echo $element->nodeValue;
}

?>


Why are you using the error suppression operator in there? Not a good idea in general, and especially not in code you have trouble to get working as desired to begin with. Have you verified whether $data contains what you expected it to, first of all?

Actually, I use ready-made code, I just make changes to it, I can get the text from the site with xpath, but I can't get the img.

Then likely either your xpath expression isn't correct for what you are trying to match; or what you are matching in, doesn't actually contain what you think it does. Both not verifiable with the info we have so far.

So can I colorize according to the resulting value?
simple : $elements = $xpath->query('//*[@id="list-rankup"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[6]');
Online(green)
Offline(red)

If the existence or non-existence of that image allows you to come to that conclusion, sure ...? (Keep in mind, we still don't know what page you are talking about to begin with here.)

No image I'm talking about the text simple site :
http://ts3.paladinsgaming.com/ts3rank/stats/top_all.php?lang=en
Top10 players
Simple 1. Player Status Online or Offline
xpath: //*[@id="page-wrapper"]/div/div[6]/div/h4[1]/span
